# Convergence in convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

This is an exercise in Rudin's Functional analysis, which is 6.23.

The problem:

$f_i \in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n), \ \lim\limits_{i \to \infty}(f_i*\phi)(x)$exists, $\forall \phi \in \mathscr{D}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Prove that $D^{\alpha}(f_i*\phi)$ converge uniformly on compact sets, for each multi-index $\alpha$

It is equivalent to prove that $f_i*\phi$ converge in $C^\infty$, then I want to show that it's a Cauchy sequence, but I don't know how to continue. I also think the Banach-Steinhaus can be used, but it can only get the equicontinuity of $f_i$ when we fix $x$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't $D^\alpha (f_i*\phi) = f_i*(D^\alpha \phi)$?

Comment: Yes, then $D^{\alpha}(f_i*\phi)$ converge pointwise.

Comment: $\phi$ is $C^\infty$ with compact support? then so is $D^\alpha \phi$, and $D^\alpha \phi \ast f$ is $C^\infty$ for any $f \in L^1_{loc}$. and the fact that $f_i \ast \phi$ converges for every $\phi$ should prove that $f_i \to f$ in $L^1_{loc}$

Comment: Yes, $\mathscr{D}$ is $C^{\infty}_0$.